# ACRCloud external meta data and IDs not returning

Tags: acrcloud

When making valid requests to http://ap-southeast-1.api.acrcloud.com/v1/identify I get successful responses, however both external_ids and external_metadata always come back as empty objects.

Example response:

```
{
  "external_ids": {},
  "play_offset_ms": 97480,
  "external_metadata": {},
  "label": "Universal Music Ltd.",
  "release_date": "2012-01-01",
  "album": {
    "name": "The Love Club EP"
  },
  "title": "Royals",
  "duration_ms": "190185",
  "genres": [
    {
      "name": "Pop"
    }
  ],
  "acrid": "b748d828aba29c699f732bd660123bae",
  "result_from": 3,
  "artists": [
    {
      "name": "Lorde"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone know why all my identifications wouldn't contain this data?

Answer (score 0):

Please select the 3rd party ID integration while creating the projects.